# What font is used for the file extensions in mac icons?

Tags: macos, mac, icon, font

The fonts on one of our macs have become corrupted. I was able to fix most of the problem by copying across a non-corrupt version of Lucida Grande from another Mac. However, the font used to display the file extension on the icons remains corrupted.

The image below shows a non-corrupted version of what I am referring to:

[image: icon]

What font is used to display the filetype in the above image?

Comment: I suggest trying the Helvetica Neue and Avenir families, as Apple [uses](http://gizmodo.com/5930274/this-is-apples-new-favorite-typeface) them elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I think it was Helvetica Neue. If you make that comment into an answer I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest trying the Helvetica Neue and Avenir families, as Apple uses them elsewhere.

Comment: Yep. It was Helvetica Neue.